# When is a common emitter amplifier a good idea?

Tags: transistors, feedback, common-emitter

[image: Common emitter voltage regulator]

In the datasheet for the LT1789 they have this application circuit. This TIP127 appears to be a voltage controlled by that opamp and placed in a common emitter configuration so it has an exponential dependence on it's base voltage. Why is this stable/a good idea? How is this opamp capable of stabilizing this? Is there some back of the envelope calculation/intuition for when designing a circuit like this is okay?

Comment: There's a lot going on in this simple circuit, two poles (R3/C3 and C2/R4) and a Deboo integrator (C1 et al) - good question +1.

Comment: Yeah! There's no emitter degeneration or anything. It seems so deceptively simple.

Comment: Almost certainly the work of the late Jim Williams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TIP127 is there to lend some grunt brute force so that currents greater than about 50 mA can easily be created at the output. Because the lower op amp "measures" that current and is in a negative feedback loop with the op amp that drives the transistor, the non linearities of the transistor are of no great consequence.

Stability can be a significant problem on circuits like this but, C1 reduces the loop gain at high frequencies ensuring phase margin never drops close to the oscillation point.